# Phonegap Build. Windows Phone Push Notification Support

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, push-notification, phonegap-build, mpns

im currently using https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/324 plugin but it has no support for windows phone. is there any plugin out there that can be used in conjuction with phonegap build that supports notifications in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I tried [pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/) on wp8, it is very simple and works!

I am pretty sure it works also on other platforms.

[Pushplugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) is supposed to support wp8 as well now but to me is not working and impossible to get support.